# Nissan Navara 2005 Automatic

Tags: nissan, stall

My Son drove 15 hours to Brisbane no problem but 10 minutes from Ipswich on the motor way it just stopped suddenly, not overheated or anything.  I thought it must be electrical, told looks like drive shaft issue, is there something electrical possible with driveshaft or is that all mechanical?

Comment: How does it look like a driveshaft issue? More details please, alternator fail or out of fuel is the most common cause of sudden unexpected stop on highway.

Comment: Although it's not usually as sudden with the gas... I'm not sure about the alternator

Answer (score 1):

Drive shaft is if your engine works, you can switch every gear, but the car won't go anywhere, might be stopping when engage a clutch. Drive shaft has nothing to do with engine or gearbox, so they should stay intact if it is a driveshaft.